# A line in this translator json file not printing correctly

Tags: json

I have a translation json file for a game I play and I have been slowly updating it these last few months since the person updating it stopped. I have been adding names to it every so often when I find anything not translated for the viewer , but the only one that seems to not work it the Heywood L.E. line below

```
    "Samuel B.Roberts":"Samuel B. Roberts",
"Samuel B.Roberts Mk.II":"Samuel B. Roberts Mk.II",
"Samuel B.Roberts改":"Samuel B. Roberts Kai",
"Fletcher":"Fletcher",
"Fletcher Mk.II":"Fletcher Mk.II",
"Fletcher改":"Fletcher Kai",
"Fletcher改 Mod.2":"Fletcher Kai Mod.2",
"Johnston":"Johnston",
"Johnston改":"Johnston Kai",
"Heywood L.E.":"Heywood L. Edwards",
"Heywood L.E.改":"Heywood L. Edwards Kai",
```

Every other name prints correctly except Heywoods which keeps it normal L.E. at the end. Is there something in the Heywood lines that are stopping it from translating just those 2 lines?
https://puu.sh/JMGPE/7a1cf4ca5c.png
It will always show up like that in the picture compared to every other name being translated.

Rewriting the lines in different ways